# How to get the value of controls inside aspx page with reflection

Tags: asp.net, reflection, controls

Hello i'm using this to get the value of a control but control collection is null:

```
        Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType("~/Default.aspx");

        Page pageView = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        Label lbl1 = (Label) pageView.FindControl("lbl1");

        string lbl1Value = lbl1.Text;
```

If add a quick watch in Visual Studio i can see that PageView.Context has the value of the label, but PageView.Context is protected, so i don't know how to access it at runtime

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense, why would you use reflection for a thing like this? Why do you create a new page with Activator?? Are you sure you know how websites work?

Comment: this have a big a very big sense: i need to access some cotrols value from backoffice, outside the scope of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, the page doesn't show controls value during reflection because i've setted the property autoevent wireup=false